# EntityType 'Message' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType - the remake

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the above error message when trying to add a migration. I have used the [Key] attribute and, in any case, the ID field is named MessageId.

What else could be causing this problem? Here is my class:

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageId;
    public string Content;
    public DateTime DateCreated;
    public User Author;
}
```

Please help!

Mark

Comment: You should have edited your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16509542/861716).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use properties, what you currently have are fields.

MessageId should become:

```
public int MessageId { get; set; }
```

Etc.(goes for the rest of the fields as well)